# Should "traffic" and "traffic-laws" be synonymized?

Tags: discussion, status-completed, tag-synonyms

We currently have four questions tagged [traffic](https://law.stackexchange.com/questions/tagged/traffic) and 13 tagged [traffic-laws](https://law.stackexchange.com/questions/tagged/traffic-laws). None of them have both tags.

The two seem to be essentially the same thing; I can't differentiate them based on the questions.

Should the two be synonymized?

Answer (score 2, accepted):

Agreed and done. A new synonym is born.

Comment: Well, that was easy.