# IP vs IP-Law. Is there a difference?

Tags: discussion, tags

We've got two tags.

[intellectual-property](https://law.stackexchange.com/questions/tagged/intellectual-property) and [intellectual-property-law](https://law.stackexchange.com/questions/tagged/intellectual-property-law).

Having the word "law" after a single tag is rather redundant.

There was this [The [tag] vs [tag-law] meta-discussion](https://law.meta.stackexchange.com/questions/237/the-tag-vs-tag-law-meta-discussion) proposal, but it seems to have fallen behind. Is there any reason to have two separate tags like this? Can they be merged?

Answer (score 4):

I'd love to revisit this, and the other [[tag] vs [tag-law] examples](https://law.meta.stackexchange.com/q/237/10) that *have not* been merged.  Every time I see one of these I stop and wonder ... so it is a distraction.  And it is messy.

Let's do this: If

1. You (or anyone) reviews the tagged questions on each and can't articulate any meaningful distinction – even one that *could* be useful if we did a cleanup – and
2. Within the next week nobody offers a plausible suggestion as to why they should be separate,

then we'll make `intellectual-property-law` a synonym for `intellectual-property`.

Comment: Sounds good to me! :)

Comment: It appears that these tags are still distinct right now. What is the process for merging them?

Comment: @rhymes_with_dorange - Thanks for drawing my attention to this.  I just merged them.