# Should the "employment" and "employment-law" tags be merged?

Tags: discussion, status-completed, tags, tag-synonyms

Should the [employment](https://law.stackexchange.com/questions/tagged/employment) and [employment-law](https://law.stackexchange.com/questions/tagged/employment-law) tags be merged?

It seems to me that as a law-specific site, the former seems a duplication and redundant - although it does have the better (only!) usage guidance:

> For questions that are about, or that arise as a result of, workplaces or the performance of work-related duties.

Comment: Duplicate of [The {tag} vs {tag-law} meta-discussion](https://law.meta.stackexchange.com/q/237/10)?

Comment: I’m voting to close this question because the tags have been merged.