# Merger of [Trees] and [Treelaw]

Tags: discussion, status-completed, tags, tag-synonyms

We have both the tags [trees](https://law.stackexchange.com/questions/tagged/trees) and [treelaw](https://law.stackexchange.com/questions/tagged/treelaw). Both are about the same item: trees and their impact on property law. As such, they should be merged.

Which one should be retained and synonymized to the other?

Answer (score 3, accepted):

I say keep [trees](https://law.stackexchange.com/questions/tagged/trees) because usage shows this is what people are gravitating towards.

Comment: And a [previous meta discussion from 2015](https://law.meta.stackexchange.com/a/240/46948) said to prefer `[tag:topic]` over `[tag:topic-law]`.